# When using the MIPS instruction set, why would it be more beneficial to use a shift left logical rather than use the offset in the load/store word?

Tags: c, mips, logical-operators, bit-shift

I have a homework question that asks:

Assume that the variables `f`, `g`, `h`, `i`, and `j` are assigned to registers `$s0`, `$s1`, `$s2`, `$s3`, and `$s4`, respectively. Assume that the base address of the arrays `A` and `B` are in registers `$s6` and `$s7`, respectively.

```
B[8] = A[i–j];
```

For the C statement above, what is the corresponding MIPS assembly code?

The answer is:

```
SUB $t0, $s3, $s4

SLL $t0, $t0, 2

ADD $t0, $t0, $s6

lw $t1, 0($t0)  # A[i - j] in is $t1
```

and

```
ADDI $t0, $zero, 8

SLL $t0, $t0, 2

ADD $t0, $t0, $s7

SW $t1, 0($t0)  # $t1 is Stored in B[8]
```

My question is, why even bother with the first 3 lines in the second block of code? If you know `$t1` is to be stored in the eighth element of `array B`, then the only instruction needed would be `SW $t1, 32($s7)`. If I'm not mistaken this is equivalent to the second block of code.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Any decent optimizing compiler would do exactly what you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is that even if both snippets of code produce the same results, i.e.

```
  ADDI $t0, $zero, 8
  SLL $t0, $t0, 2
  ADD $t0, $t0, $s7
  SW $t1, 0($t0)  # $t1 is Stored in B[8]
```

and

```
  SW $t1, 32($s7)  # $t1 is Stored in B[8]
```

the first one consumes more CPU cycles.

Any simple compiler would be able to issue the first chunk of code, as it's a direct translation of the high level statement `B[8] = result_of_calculation`.

The second chunk of code need a little bit of static analysis (i.e. the compiler has to take into account that `$s7` holds the base address of array B and also take into account that you will address the eight location of such array.

My guess is that any modern compiler perform that minimal static analysis and therefore would issue the second instruction instead of the first chunk of code.